# Регулярное выражение на адрес страницы ВКонтакте

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Помогите составить регулярное выражение JavaScript. Вот какие данные должны пропускаться:

http://vk.com/user/
http://vk.com/user
[vk.com/user/](http://vk.com/user/)
[vk.com/user](http://vk.com/user)
[www.vk.com/user/](http://www.vk.com/user/)
[www.vk.com/user](http://www.vk.com/user)

Понятно, что "user" это любой текст. Также это может быть "id123456".

Comment: Вот что сам попробовал:

    /^(((https?)\:\/\/)?(www\.)?)?(vk\.com\/[A-Za-z0-9-]\/?)$/gi

Честно признаться мало чего в этом понимаю.

Comment: А какие ещё символы могут быть в имени пользователя? Подчёркивание? Кириллица?

Comment: Самые первые скобки - лишние

Comment: В имени пользователя могут быть только латинские символы, цифры (от 1 до 9) и символ нижнего подчёркивания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот еще рабочий вариант:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?vk\.com\/(\w|\d)+?\/?$
```

Comment: тогда возможно \d и не надо. Ведь \w вроде включает в себя цифры.

Comment: Немного улучшу Ваше выражение

    ^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?vk\.com\/(.*)\/?$

Comment: можно вообще не парится с этими регулярками, а сделать массив адресов =)

Comment: при (.*)\/?$ попадет все что стоит после vk.com/
например: http://vk.com/id1324324?get=/adsfdasf

Comment: а вообще согласен, что-то я перемудрил малость )
тогда может быть лучше так?
> ^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\\.)?vk\\.com\/[^\/\s]+\/?$

Comment: @ReinRaus, просьба высказаться [**здесь**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29725433#29725433) насчёт метасимволов границ строки в примерах регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?(vk\.com|vkontakte\.ru)\/(id\d|[a-zA-Z0-9_.])+$
```

Comment: Слэш в конце, который нужен автору, не отображается, но, полагаю, он тут лишний. Валидные *id* на настоящий момент ограничены девятью цифрами, можно уточнить — `\d{9})`. Итог: `(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?(vk\.com|vkontakte\.ru)\/(id(\d{9})|[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)`. Демонстрация — https://regex101.com/r/mB9aK1/1 . Спасибо.

Comment: Не пропустит vk.com/id12345

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вот решение лучше

```
(https{0,1}:\/\/)?(www\.)?(vk.com\/)(id\d|[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]{2,})
```

Так как username не может начинаться с цифры, например так: https://vk.com/1111111

Comment: вместо `s{0,1}` лучше писать `s?`.

Comment: дело вкуса, для меня читаемость с фигурными скобками в некоторых местах лучше.